# Displaying SKNode over UIView in SKView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKScene in which i have bunch of sprites and physic stuff. I needed to add UIView to SKView who presented the scene. Now i need to put some SKNode over UIView. But when I add child to my scene, UIView is displayed at top, and newly added nodes stays below. Is it possible to show newly added nodes over UIView components ?

Comment: Not sure but see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970143/2158465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You already have a UIView which you can access in the view from `didMoveToView:(SKView *)view`. All nodes reside in that view. If you add another view, it either goes in front or behind the 'SKView'.