# SKScene Vs SKView

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

What are differences between Scene and View? I also read [Cocoa: scene vs. view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229990/cocoa-scene-vs-view) but I don't understand  differences. I appreciated if you give an example.

Comment: Did you read the [SceneKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012282)? Have you read the documentation for `SKScene` and `SKView`? What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Your linked info is about scenes in Storyboard, not SpriteKit (SK) scenes. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21952116/1457385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation.

SpriteKit content is placed in a window, just like other visual content. SpriteKit content is rendered by the SKView class. The content that an SKView object renders is called a scene, which is an SKScene object. Scenes participate in the responder chain and have other features that make them appropriate for games.

An SKScene object represents a scene of content in Sprite Kit. A scene is the root node in a tree of Sprite Kit nodes (SKNode). These nodes provide content that the scene animates and renders for display. To display a scene, you present it from an SKView object